# Como puedo mostrar una imagen en mi pagina web con google drive?

Tags: html, api, google-drive

e estado investigando y no encuentro ningun metodo para visualizar una imagen de google drive en una etiqueta img, embed, etc, en html. anteriormente me funcionaba con el siguiente codigo html `<img src='https://drive.google.com/uc?&id=[id de tu imagen]' />` como un ejemplo `<img src='https://drive.google.com/uc?&id=13aW1fV26g2nQOoAiYPH5v7dnN0m3keLM' />` si lo abres en la web te mostrara la imagen pero en cuanto lo pongas tal cual en una etiqueta html no te funcionara, me aparece en consola lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero y alguien sepa como solucionar este, si hay una nueva url para esta, o una sintaxis, etc, agradezco de antemano si alguien sabe...